# A function $f$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ that satisfies $f'(0)<0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

If I have a function $f$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ with continuous derivative and that satisfies $f’(0)<0$, then can we state for sure that on some initial interval $[0,x_0]$, $f$ decreases?

If I’m thinking about it using definition of derivative with limits, it should be the case. I just want to make sure it is true and in case it isn’t what else should we determine in order for this statement to be true?

Comment: For sure, $f'(x) <0$ in $[0,x_0]$ for some $x_0$.

Comment: You don't even need the definition of the derivative, all you need is that if $g$ is continuous and $g(a)<0$, then $g(x)<0$ for all $x$ in some interval around $a$

Comment: The continuity of $f'$ is only useful at $0$ (see the duplicate).

Comment: Yes, it is fine. I just needed at least some small interval where f would be decreasing initially.